# Sum mathematical series. Bash

Tags: linux, bash, shell, math

I can not understand the work of Linux shell: how to calculate the sum of mathematical series? I would be grateful if someone will throw a few examples.

ps.Need examples for infinite series.

My example: 
Sum(n=0,inf)((-1)^n) * ((1/10*n+1) - (1/1-*n+3) + (1/10*n+5) - (1/10*n+7) + (1/10*n+9))

Comment: Example needs to come from you like what you want to sum?

Comment: If you don't understand bash at all, any solution given to you would be as meaningful as این چیزی که اینجا نوشتم. You should perhaps start learning the basics of bash before trying to do something more complicated.

Comment: "این چیزی که اینجا نوشتم." = "This is what I wrote here." You are underestimating the power of google translate :)

Comment: @JoeC unfortunately the same cannot be achieved with code! If it did you'd be very famous and rich!

Comment: In any event, the shell is an extremely poor choice of tool for arithmetic.

Comment: @JoeC, right. And we know `seq 1 2 19 | awk '{sum+=$1} END {print sum}'` does what the question asks, but that doesn't necessarily mean you _understood_ it ;) (P.S. the actual translation would be: ... as meaningful as _what I wrote here_, but it's ok for GT to get it wrong because it wasn't a complete sentence on its own)

Answer (score 3):

You can sum a series of numbers using `bc`:

```
$ echo "2+3+4" | bc
9
```

You can do this a little more programmatically using seq:

```
$ seq 2 3 20 | xargs | tr " " "+" | bc
77
```

Combine `seq` and `awk` to sum with a bit more complexity and control:

```
seq 1 2 19 | awk '{sum+=$1} END {print sum}'
```

However, if you're trying to sum an infinite series, this won't work well. You'll probably want to pull out your calculus book and open up a UNIX socket.

Answer (score 3):

http://www.sal.ksu.edu/faculty/tim/unix_sg/bash/math.html

for integer math:

```
$ declare -i n
$ n=6/3
$ echo $n
2
```

for floating point

```
$ r=3.5
$ s=`echo "$r + 2.2" | bc`
$ echo $s
5.7
```